# iPhone: Maintain Timer value between different views

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I have built iPhone game application which has loads of views. The next view gets decided based on the user's current action. It working fine absolutely. I want to start a timer when my game gets started and want to keep incrementing till game finished. Nothing fency! The problem is I can put label on view and use NS Timer ticks to increment its value but how to synchronize that value when move to next view?

Could anyone please let me know if there is already framwork available that support this or any way to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have the timer be a property in your app delegate, so you can access it from any view/view controller.  That's what I'd do here.  It doesn't seem to "belong" to individual views based on what you've described.